# power/sample size for a complex set of equations

Tags: multilevel-analysis, panel-data, statistical-power, structural-equation-modeling

I run an experiment in which several teams perform several tasks each (not all teams perform all tasks, but in general, I can make sure that enough teams perform any given task, and that each team performs enough tasks). I have 30 different tasks, but for the sake of the question let's say its t tasks, g teams and that each team performs k tasks.

The outcome depends on some team level known variables (controls), but mainly on 9 variables that I need to estimate. in each task the weight of the different variable is different (but known). This can be summarized in the following equation:

$T_i = controls_{team(i)} + \sum_{j=1}^9 w_j^{task(i)}*v_j + \epsilon_i$

my question would be  how can I compute power in this setting. specifically I want to be able to calculate the sample size (e.g. the number of teams and/or the number of repetition per team and/or the number of different tasks) in order to estimate the $v_j$ variables reliably.

I know that if I had only one task this would look like a regular linear regression, but as the weights are fixed, it would be non-identified model. with 30 tasks it is identified model (at least in theory), but I can't figure out how to calculate power. It seems related to SEM in that each tasks yields a different equation based on its known weights. it also seems relevant to panel data analysis because of the team*task structure. I'm not expert in either, so I may be wrong.

Any help/insights/references are welcome.

Comment: The general answer to "how do I compute power for a complex situation"? Is "simulate data sets that are reasonably realistic for your situation, analyze them in the way that you intend to analyze the real data, and summarize the fraction of times that you are satisfied with the outcome (significant p-value, standard error or CV of coefficient estimate below a specified thresholds, etc.)"

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do use simulations of the sort you suggest. However, I am a firm believer of not re-inventing the wheel, and of learning and utilizing others' knowledge and experience. While it might be that my specific scenario is unique, I do believe that the general issue of simultaneously estimating multiple equations has been studied. I'm looking for references to such knowledge so I don't repeat the mistakes of others. I want to learn. Anyway - thanks.

Comment: perhaps the problem here is that you have two questions: (1) how do I simultaneously estimate multiple equations and (2) how do I compute power for this approach?  I was answering the second, but maybe you're more interested in answers to the first.

Comment: @BenBolker I appreciate your efforts.